# socket code not working inside Codeigniter rest api

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, websocket

I am working on codeigniter rest api,and at the sametime i need to push some count message via socket, so i have written js code using echo (to run js code in php we need echo), but socket code is not working, i.e at receiver side I am not getting any message.

socket code in rest api file:

```
     if ($this->db->insert('users', $new_arr)) {
                    echo '<script src="' . base_url("node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/socket.io.js") . '"></script>';
    echo " var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' )";// open connection at sender
                    echo 'socket.emit("new_count_message", {  // emit message
                      new_count_message: 145
                    })';
                    $response = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'data dded successfully', 'response' => array());
                } else {
                    $response = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Failed to add data!');
                }
              $this->response($response);
```

At rceiver:

```
    var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );// connection open at receiver
     socket.on( 'new_count_message', function( data ) {
     alert(data.new_count_message);
  
      $( "#new_count_message" ).html( data.new_count_message );
   $('#notif_audio')[0].play();

  });
```

Comment: It looks like both your receiver and your html rendered by the rest api file are trying to connect to a socket, but it doesn't look like you are opening a socket connection anywhere. You can follow the docs here https://socket.io/docs/v3/index.html to use sockets with an existing `httpserver` under "Minimal working example". Basically, the connection needs to be open as long as the server is running, and is separate from the webpage generated and returned from your API. Your rest api file is "emitting" to nothing, as it isn't connected to any active socket.

Comment: @sal I have opened connection please check  my code, sender and receiver bth side connection is opened and I am running node ser.js file via cmd which is located in project directory

Comment: Where are you opening the connection? The rest api file looks like it's returning a webpage, and the `io.connect()` method inside of there is looking to connect to an open socket, not open one. If you're opening it somewhere else, please include that code as well, or correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Sal I have updated my questionin same way i did in previous website (sending and receiving done from webpage) and  in that case it worked fine, but here I am sending from api and try to receive at webpage

Comment: I don't have extensive experience with `websockets`, however anytime I've used `socket.io` (in node), I have always emitted a message from a client to a server, and then the server would emit the message to the appropriate clients. I'm not aware of any way to emit from one client directly to another without a server, which is what your code seems to be doing. Your API file doesn't seem to be serving as the server socket connection, it's just returning `HTML` so that the client can connect to a `socket`, but that open `socket` isn't in this code.  Try https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io?

Comment: @Sal  can u please tell me any way how to emit message from server to client i.e message should emit from rest api and output should come in html page(website)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't working with `socket.io` in php, however I came across this library https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io that allows you to implement `socket.io` in php. Following the "Simple chat" example should show you how you can set up the server-side code. What you have in your api file doesn't open a server-side connection, rather returns a website that emits data from the client side. Because you don't have a server handling socket connections, it is unable to transmit the data to other sockets. After configuring your server-side socket handler, when the API call is made and the code in your API file is called, the client will receive a webpage with the information you have outputted. In the received data, you are connecting to a socket and emitting data. That data will then be received by the server in the code you implemented following the example I linked, then emit the data to the connections you had set.

Alternatively, rather than making an API call in the first place, why don't you just emit a message instead? This will save you a network call (the API call is unnecessary if all it is doing is triggering the socket) and should make your application faster. It's hard to give exact implementation details without seeing how the API is being called in the first place.